# create xml string and use xquery to extract data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

How can I create an XML string on the fly using jquery and afterwards use Xquery to query  information like i would do on server side e.g php/database

Can anyone show my possible ways of how to do this ?

thank you as I will appreciate any of your input!!!!!!

Comment: Why do you want to create an XML? Why don't you create a JSON instead? Where do you want to use it? How large is the dataset? How deep is the dataset?

Comment: lets say i have an array like this $string='{"person":
         [
   {
    "name":{"first":"John","last":"Adams"},
                "age":"40",location:"london"
   },
   {
    "name":{"first":"Thomas","last":"Jefferson"},
                "age":"35",location:london
   }
   ]
   }'; and i want to count and output how many times london is in this array,how would i do that?

Comment: window.alert(JSON.parse(string).filter(function(elem){return elem.location==="london";}).length) in javascript, sorry for the short form, this is a comment, look up filter on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter